# PHP Include not working - Hostgator

Tags: php, html

I have a booking script installed on my server and it says to include the small calendar in your website to use php include.

My code is

```
<div class="calendarcontainer">
<?php include (http://www.jetnightclub.com/booking/calendar.php); ?>
</div>
```

And nothing happens. When I go direct to the page it is there so the server is reading the php... not sure why it won't puck ut up.

**Warning** : The link is NSFW it is a website for a nightclub. If that is a problem please do not open it.

Comment: RTFM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

Comment: One certain problem, one potential.  The URL is a _string_ and must therefore be quoted as a string. That is a certain problem.  The potential problem is that `allow_url_include` is possibly turned off even when you do fix the quoting.

Comment: quotes didnt work and not sure what the other thing is lol. I am going to bed it is 4:30 am and am exhausted. thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the quotes here. Refer to the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

this is the fix :

```
        <div class="calendarcontainer">
        <?php include ("http://www.jetnightclub.com/booking/calendar.php"); ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in your php.ini file on your hosting server.

```
allow_url_include=On
```

Then restart web server.
Then you can use the code like this:

```
<div class="calendarcontainer">
    <?php include ("http://www.jetnightclub.com/booking/calendar.php"); ?>
</div>
```